# When not to use MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

This is not a question on specific technical coding aspect of MPI. I am NEW to MPI, and not wanting to make a fool of myself of using the library in a wrong way, thus posting the question here.

As far as I understand, MPI is a environment for building parallel application on a distributed memory model.

I have a system that's interconnected with Infiniband, for the sole purpose of doing some very time consuming operations. I've already broke out the algorithm to do it in parallel, so I am really only using MPI to transmit data (results of the intermediate steps) between multiple nodes over Infiniband, which I believe one can simply use OpenIB to do.

Am I using MPI the right way? Or am I bending the original intention of the system?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what MPI was designed for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fewer and simpler the MPI constructs you need to use to get your work done, the *better* MPI is a match to your problem -- you can say that about most libraries and lanaguages, as a practical matter and argualbly an matter of abstractions.

Yes, you could write raw OpenIB calls to do your work too, but what happens when you need to move to an ethernet cluster, or huge shared-memory machine, or whatever the next big interconnect is?  MPI is middleware, and as such, one of its big selling points is that you don't have to spend time writing network-level code.

Comment: +1 No idea about the down vote, good point and makes perfect sense!

Comment: it answers my question, and I think I agree with you that using MPI does give me the ability to abstract away the underlying communication mechanism and thus more extensible (within the realm of MPI of course).

Comment: I disagree that you should use as few MPI constructs as possible.  You should use the RIGHT constructs - no more, no less.

Comment: @Jeff Who said that thing you're disagreeing with?

Comment: @JonathanDursi I was responding to "The fewer and simpler the MPI constructs you need to use to get your work done, the better MPI is a match to your problem..."  Maybe you weren't arguing for using as few MPI constructs as possible, but it seemed that way.

Comment: @Jeff One's a question of impedance mismatch; the other is a question of blindly counting features used. One's a question of abstractions; the other is one of how you choose to use an API.  One suggests a way of choosing between tools; the other is about how you choose to use a given tool.  These are pretty fundamental distinctions, and if the above isn't clear, please do suggest an edit to clarify things - but I've re-read the question and the answer, and this confusion doesn't seem evident to me; no one else has seemed confused by it over 3 years.

Answer (score 5):

Its fine to use just MPI_Send & MPI_Recv in your algorithm. As your algorithm evolves, you gain more experience, etc. you may find use for the more "advanced" MPI features such as barrier & collective communication such as Gather, Reduce, etc.

Comment: Send-Recv are low level primitives.  You should aspire to use collectives first since they are much easier to reason about.  And many of the common patterns people use Send-Recv for can now be expressed in MPI-3's neighborhood collectives.

Answer (score 0):

At the other end of the complexity spectrum, the time not to use MPI is when your problem or solution technique presents enough dynamism that MPI usage (most specifically, its process model) is a hindrance. A system like [Charm++](http://charm.cs.illinois.edu) (disclosure: I'm a developer of Charm++) lets you do problem decomposition in terms of finer grained units, and its runtime system manages the distribution of those units to processors to ensure load balance, and keeps track of where they are to direct communication appropriately.

Another not-uncommon issue is dynamic data access patterns, where something like Global Arrays or a PGAS language would be much easier to code.

Comment: You are talking about usage of MPI, not what MPI is.  That Charm++ can sit on top of MPI proves that MPI is fine for dynamic computation - one just has to implement the dynamism or get it from middleware like Charm++.

Comment: Charm++ _can_ sit on top of MPI, but that is *not* the preferred network back-end.  The two are just different - e.g., "Regardless of specific implementation details, we believe there is a fundamental difference between the expected-message nature of MPI and the unexpected-message behavior of Charm++. This difference makes the former less suited to performing the communication responsibilities of the latter.", [Gunter et al](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~balaji/pubs/2013/charm/charm13.charmpi.pdf)

Comment: You might want to see "Optimizing Charm++ over MPI" on Google Scholar.  It is possible to improve the performance quite a bit by tuning MPI for the Charm++ usage model, in which most (all?) messages are unexpected.